# Cannot re-use variable assigned within a computation expression

Tags: f#

I'm trying to use computational expressions to create a builder-like DSL, but when I try to use let assignments to help compose things, I get a compilation error that such assignments cannot be found. Here's an example:

```
type Node = 
    {
        Key: Option<string>
        Children: List<Node>
        XPathFromParent: string
    }


let defaultNode = 
    {
        Key = None; 
        Children = [];
        XPathFromParent = ".//somePath"
    }


type NodeBuilder(xpath: string) =
    member self.Yield(item: 'a): Node =  defaultNode

    member this.xpath = xpath

    [<CustomOperation("xpath_from_parent")>]
    member __.XPathFromParent (node, x) = {node with XPathFromParent = x}

    [<CustomOperation("nodes")>]
    member __.Nodes (node, x) = {node with Children = x}

    [<CustomOperation("key")>]
    member __.MidasMeasurementKey (node, x) = {node with Key = x}

    member this.Bind(x, f) = f x


let node xpath = NodeBuilder(xpath)


let rootNode = node ".//somePath" {
    let! childNodes = 
        [
            node "somepath" {
                nodes []
            };

            node "someOtherPath" {
                nodes []
            }
        ]

    nodes childNodes  // The value or constructor 'childNodes' is not defined.
}
```

How can I alter this code so that I can reference the `childNodes` assignment to pass it into the `nodes` custom operator?

Answer (score 5):

Your immediate problem is that you need to put a `[<ProjectionParameter>]` attribute on any arguments to custom operators that you wish to be able to access the variable space of the computation expression.  However, once you add this, you'll find that you have some problems with mismatched types.  In general, I agree with [rmunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314532/rmunn): computation expressions are not necessarily a good fit for your problem, so you should strongly consider using a different mechanism instead.

However, if you insist on pushing onwards, here's one trick to help you debug.  It looks like you want to be able to write

```
node "something" {
    let! childNodes = ([some expression]:Node list)
    nodes childNodes
}
```

So create a dummy builder like this (the seemingly useless `Quote` method is the key):

```
type DummyNodeBuilder(xpath:string) = 
    [<CustomOperation("nodes")>]
    member __.Nodes (node:Node, [<ProjectionParameter>]x) = node // Note: ignore x for now and pass node through unchanged
    member __.Yield(_) = Unchecked.defaultof<_> // Note: don't constrain types at all
    member __.Bind(_,_) = Unchecked.defaultof<_> // Note: don't constrain types at all
    member __.Quote() = ()

let node xpath = DummyNodeBuilder xpath

let expr = 
    node "something" {
        let! childNodes = [] : Node list
        nodes childNodes
    }
```

and you'll see that `expr` holds a quotation roughly equivalent to:

```
builder.Nodes(
    builder.Bind([], 
                 fun childNodes -> builder.Yield childNodes),
    fun childNodes -> childNodes)
```

so in your real builder you'll need to have methods that have compatible signatures (e.g. `Nodes`'s second argument must accept a function, and the first argument must be compatible with the return type of `Bind`, etc.).  As you try out other workflows you'd like to enable with the dummy builder, you can see how they desugar and discover additional constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Computation expressions can be difficult to use until you *fully* understand how they work. If you're relatively new to F#, I'd suggest going about it without the computation expressions, using plain function calls and lists to construct your nodes. Something like the following:

```
type Node = 
    {
        Key: Option<string>
        Children: List<Node>
        XPathFromParent: string
    }

let defaultNode = 
    {
        Key = None; 
        Children = [];
        XPathFromParent = ".//somePath"
    }

let withNodes children node = { node with Children = children }
let withXpathFromParent xpath node = { node with XPathFromParent = xpath }
let withKey key node = { node with Key = Some key }

let mkNode xpath children = { Key = None
                              Children = children
                              XPathFromParent = xpath }

// Usage example

let rootNode =
    mkNode ".//somePath" [
        mkNode "somepath" [] |> withKey "childkey1"
        mkNode "someOtherPath" [] // No key specified, so this one will be None
    ] |> withKey "parentKey"
```

That produces a `rootNode` that looks like this:

```
val rootNode : Node =
  {Key = Some "parentKey";
   Children =
    [{Key = Some "childkey1";
      Children = [];
      XPathFromParent = "somepath";}; {Key = null;
                                       Children = [];
                                       XPathFromParent = "someOtherPath";}];
   XPathFromParent = ".//somePath";}
```

Comment: Hey @rmunn, you've correctly guessed that I'm new to F# :). However, I really am specifically looking for how to do this with computation expressions. What I'm trying to do is create a builder DSL that even non-technical people could write for a business-specific problem my company is having - in my opinion the hypothetical version with computation expressions is much more easy on the eyes. If it were for just technical people only I would do as you have wisely suggested.

Comment: Then I won't be able to help you much: I can reproduce your problem, but it's stumping me, too. Best suggestion I can make is to sprinkle `printfn` statements, aka the poor man's debugger :-), into your builder and see when (and if) they get called.

Comment: But another suggestion I have is if you're wanting to build a DSL for non-techies, computation expressions may not be as good as rolling your own little language with [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html). The error messages from computation expressions tend to be a little opaque even to experienced developers; non-techies will find it *impossible* to figure out that they (say) left out a word (e.g., wrote `[]` when they should have written `nodes []`). Whereas if you use FParsec to give them a custom language to write in, you can control the syntax and error messages.

Comment: @nebffa: In my experience you can get a pretty nice DSL by having a static class with a short (maybe even one letter) name with a bunch of overloaded methods or methods with optional arguments. I do see the appeal of what you're trying to do (and I tried something similar in the past), but it comes with it own constraints and the added accidental complexity is simply not worth it.